# Database Error On Saving Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to save data to a database;  The query I am using is

```
$sql_query = 'UPDATE ' . 'config' . ' SET current_email = "' . $_POST["an email_data"] . '"';
```

which in this case break out to

```
UPDATE config SET current_email = 'email address'
```

I keep getting mysql error `1054, unknown column 'current_email' in 'field_list'`

I have tried retyping the query and the database field to no avail. he column does exist.

I have version 5.4.3 of mySql.  I have never had this problem before and am at my wits end.  I have been dead in the water for three days know.  I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: the code is vulnerable at sql-injection and this .'config'.  no make sense

Comment: @Sam I assume `.` is concatenation operator from whatever language he's generating this query in.

Comment: @AaronLS why you concatenate a static string? just do this 'UPDATE config SET' no?

Comment: I'm thinking you probably want a WHERE clause in this query before you update the whole table with that value.  Also, double check you are pointing to the correct table and spelling everything correctly.  And maybe add php tag to get more help from PHP experts.

Comment: @michael You might want to script the table to a create statement and post that so we can see the structure.  Also, add logging to your code that generates the SQL and log the resulting $sql_query variable, the fact that your example is not consistent on the quotes tells me what you posted is what you **expect** it to generate, but you should log the variable to verify your expectations.  Then you can  run that query directly from a database manager, that way you can focus on whether the problem is with the query, or the code generating the query.

Comment: Make sure you get the meaning of `' <> "`

Answer (score 3):

In your first line you are using double quotes for the SQL string: SET current_email = **"**'

This would get rendered as:

`UPDATE config SET current_email = "email address"`

instead, try single quotes:

`UPDATE config SET current_email = 'email address'`

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

> If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, string literals can be quoted
>   only within single quotation marks because a string quoted within
>   double quotation marks is interpreted as an identifier.

Comment: Tried many variations of your suggestion.  All failed

Comment: Figured it out.  There WHERE clause was the thing; that comment got me to re-thinking the problem leading to the solution. Single quotes, double quotes make no difference by demonstration as long as they are balanced.  Of course this opens up a new problem but it is one of design, not coding.  Re sql injection, yes I know; was just trying to make the thing as simple as possible for trouble shooting. Honestly, thanks for the help.